automatic weights applied and splitting caused when using in pose mode
I am very new to blender and have created these arms, but when I try to add automatic weight to the skin/model and I try to test it using pose mode the model splits in two.
I had created the sleeves and gloves by extruding along normals and pressed Ctrl + J to join the  arm and gloves together. In Edit Mode I have also tried to merge by distance but I still have the same issue.
I am not sure why they are splitting this even happens when I try to use the vertex groups and assign them.


Hello could you please share your armature and object?
